# With Spring boot servlet contextPath then DistributedCommandBus: 404

Tags: axon, contextpath

I have two SpringBootApplication, A and B. A sends command, B handles the command.

When B start with a not empty `server.servlet.context-path`, when A send a command then show exception

```
An error occurred while trying to dispatch a command on the DistributedCommandBus: 404 null
```

I config the command router like:

```
SpringCloudCommandRouter.builder().localServiceInstance(registration).discoveryClient(discoveryClient).routingStrategy(new AnnotationRoutingStrategy()).build()
```

An error occurred while trying to dispatch a command on the:

```
DistributedCommandBus: 404 null
```

Comment: I use the Axon Framework to do with the command, 
 CommandGateway.send(command) to send a command, anyone could help ?thanks!

Comment: I'd like to ask you @G.cq to add more information to your question. Things like:
- Which Axon version do you use?
- Which implemention of Spring Cloud Discovery are you using?
- Have you set up your application to be a Discovery Client?
- A full stack trace of the exception instead of a single line.

With the current set of information I can only guess what you are doing. Thus an update to be more specific in regards to your sample app. would be highly beneficial.